# Spring Cloud Dataflow on different message broker than Redis?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

from what I can see in the documentation, always a Redis instance is needed for Spring Cloud Dataflow to work.

Is it also possible to work with different message broker, e.g. RabbitMQ?

How would one specify a different message broker during startup?

Comment: Redis is not required for Spring cloud, and you can use RabbitMQ. https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

Comment: I believe redis is required for the dataflow server, but as far as messaging, the rabbitmq and kafka are supported message brokers.

Comment: Yes, as you describe it, but currently SCDF has no notion of specifying different binder for the stream modules...I opened a ticket for this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/469. Let's see, what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

With the recent [1.0.0.M3 release](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/29/spring-cloud-data-flow-1-0-0-m3-released), when using the `Local` server, we load `kafka` based OOTB applications, by default.

If you'd like to switch from `kafka` to `rabbit`, you can via `--binder=rabbit` as a command line argument when starting the `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local` JAR (*and be sure to start the RabbitMQ server*).